# Is VARBINARY a good data type to JOIN in Snowflake?

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Topic pretty much says it all.

We want to know if using VARBINARY data type columns as primary key is going to be efficient for the joins we will build later on, on this key.

We are using Snowflake Cloud Platform.

We tried using BIGINT, but some of our generated keys were bigger than BIGINT since they are concatenated INT fields.

Answer (score 1):

The best primary keys are natural keys that are sortable - so micro-partitions can be quickly discarded when pruning the querying tree.

With that said, we've seen Snowflake performing well with millions of rows, complex multi table joins, even using MD5 keys to join.

So the most important question is what makes more sense for your overall productivity and use case, and Snowflake's performance can help you achieve those goals.

Starting with your own performance tests helps too.